# Control programmatically the reads from and writes to GCP BQ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

The requirement is to read data from multiple GCP BQ tables, do lot of transformations and then load it back to target table in GCP BQ. How do we achieve it programmatically.

Data reads and loads to GCP BQ can be done directly in BQ by using set of PL/SQLs. However for better maintainability how do we achieve this? Using combination of spark & scala and building the jar will give more flexibility on functional aspects? Should dataproc cluster be used for running the jobs in that case ?

Using spark, scala and submitting the job in dataproc is taking more time to execute. Is there any better options.

Comment: If the input and output are BigQuery, you can leverage its processing power and do all the transformations using SQL, so you don't need to extract the data somewhere else, process it, and then load it again. A tool like DBT could help a lot with that.